# Change the default '# in stock message' in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am trying to change the default "# in stock" message to "# spots available" on my site.

I tried the below code in my functions file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  global $product;
  $stock = $product->get_total_stock();

  if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __($stock . ' SPOTS LEFT', 'woocommerce');
  if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('SOLD OUT', 'woocommerce');

  return $availability;
}
```

This worked to change the text, however it added the quantity of my two variations together. So instead of saying 15 spots left for the first variation and 10 spots left for the second variation, it just said 25 spots left no matter which variation was selected.

So then I tried the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_availability', 1, 2);

function custom_get_availability( $availability, $_product ) {
  global $product;
  $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

  if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __($stock . '', 'woocommerce');
  if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('brak', 'woocommerce');

  return $availability;
}
```

And this did not work either. It did not display any quantities.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer on my own and thought it might help some folks out:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_get_availability', 99, 2 );
  
function custom_get_availability( $availability, $product ) {
   $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
   if ( $product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = $stock . ' Spots Available';
   if ( !$product->is_in_stock() && $product->managing_stock() ) $availability = 'Class Full';
   
   return $availability;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, it might even more if you could describe in one or two bullet points/sentences where your error was, so others don't have to compare your code line by line. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).